# Developed a Desktop Application by using Visual Studio 2019 and not running the setup

Tags: desktop-application, visual-studio-2019

I have developed a desktop application by using Visual Studio 2019 and setup is not running.  It is asking for install .NET Framework 4.6.1 even I installed the Framework.

[image: This is message i am getting]

Is there a way that i can fix this issue?

Additional Information:

- I have used the Windows 10 Operating System.
- I have set the .NET Framework as 4.6 in the Properties before deployment.

Comment: Target .net 4.8 (which will be last .net 4.x version before Microsoft moves to .net core codebase with .NET 5) and install .net 4.8

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you for your kind reply.  I have also tried to set the target to last version i.e. 4.7 (on my computer) and i am facing the same issue.

Comment: how do you create setup?

Comment: downloaded installer from market place.

Comment: btw, got it working. I have installed 2015 version of visual studio community and generated a setup file. Now, i am able to install the software without any problem.

Comment: this is wired. report it to Microsoft so that they can fix it